# How to batch trim 100 videos?

Tags: video-editor, editing

So I have 100 videos in a folder, I need to extract (ex.) 1:00 to 2:00. HB can do this but you have to set times for every video. Any software / Premiere script or other methods to do this?

Comment: If you're comfortable with command line apps, you could script it using FFMPEG, based on this answer: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/34363/how-do-you-trim-videos-in-ffmpeg